# Laravel Cashier - Stripe Multiple Payment Method

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'm using Laravel Cashier with Stripe for my restaurant.

I want to use multiple payment methods that Stripe supports for my customers, but i couldn't find any information about using multiple payment methods with Stripe in the [Laravel Cashier documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/billing#payment-methods).

The [Accept a Payment document](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements) in Stripe's documentation is exactly what I need. Is there a way to implement the method described in this document with Laravel Cashier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this requires to run both php and js script to stripe,

its reference [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/billing#storing-payment-methods)

you first need a setup intent, which you have to call using

```
return $user->createSetupIntent();
```

and access the value on the front-end. on your card/payment page, you have to set-up the stripe js card elements. then capture and process the card elements like example below (uses axios)

```
const { setupIntent, error } = await stripe.confirmCardSetup(your_SETUP_INTENT, {
  payment_method: {
    card: your_card_object,
    billing_details: { name: 'Card Name' }
  }
})

if (error) {
  console.log(error)
} else {
  const { data } = await axios.post('/api/payment-method', { card: setupIntent.payment_method })
}
```

once the request to stripe is successful, you'll get payment method id, which you can push back to your server like the example above, then attach the payment back that user by calling `addPaymentMethod`

```
$user->addPaymentMethod( $request->input('card) );
```

Comment: Yes, but this is code without support for Laravel and Cashier. I need to do this in Laravel Cashier.

Comment: @sercanarga, you need to read that reference I sent, my whole explanation above is for laravel cashier and based on laravel cashier docs

Comment: Yes I noticed now, sorry. But I think it's about registering the customer's payment method described here.

Comment: @sercanyou'd have to keep reading that doc until you understand it, there are no OTHER ways to do it unless you'll do it outside Casheir. I've already covered all required steps in example above like you need to use ```createSetupIntent``` and ```addPaymentMethod``` provided by laravel cashier. the connection between your card capture page and stripe is done through Stripe JS

Answer (score 0):

The SetupIntent created for collecting a payment method is default to accept [card](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents/create#create_setup_intent-payment_method_types) only. In addition, the frontend also only uses Card Element in the Laravel Cashier doc which is meant for collecting card information.

To accept other payment method types, you'll first create a SetupIntent with other [payment_method_types](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents/create#create_setup_intent-payment_method_types) at server, then pass to client secret to Payment Element instead of Card Element to render. Payment Element allows one or multiple payment methods. For more information, you can refer to the doc here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse

Please note that not all payment methods support SetupIntent (for future usage). You may refer to the doc here for the payment methods that support SetupIntent: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/integration-options#additional-api-supportability

Comment: We can help in this community space if you have further questions :)